# Earthquakes and mountain height

Tags: earthquakes, plate-tectonics, mountains

Tectonic plate motion is the main reason for earthquakes in Italy.

I suppose that a large motion produces higher mountain (as Monte Bianco, Monte Rosa or Adamello) and strong earthquakes.

But strong earthquakes are usually registered in the Apennines (not so high, with the exception of Gran Sasso) and the Julian Alps (not very high between Italy, Austria and Slovenia).

What is the reason of this counter-intuitive behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Present earthquakes create new mountains, former earthquakes created old mountains.
Hence, the Alps are older than the Appenines. In the past surely the Alps had more earthquakes than now.